# UK: Will signing up for a mobile phone contract affect my credit rating?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, mobile-phone-plans

Especially I would like to understand one thing:

There are operators who offer contracts without credit check for people who otherwise would be denied because of for example a completely missing credit history.

When signing up with one of those operators who don't do any credit checks, I wonder if on the other hand they would report the fact that my contract exists and is paid for on time will be reported and help one's credit score or if it would mean they don't work at all with credit agencies so being with them won't help with building up credit history.